# Module ldap_sso lost when updating module to the new version

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

I am in a process of updating the drupal core and some of the modules **(quite deactualized)**. One of them is `ldap` module, on this server I have no way to update through the drupal administration page, currently the installed version is `ldap 7.x-1.0-beta12`, the system will follow me to install the ldap version `7.x-1.0-beta15`.

As I mentioned, the only way I have to update is manually, I have deleted the files from the server and I have placed the new ones with the version ldap `7.x-1.0-beta15`, when I run the update **(update.php)** it appears that there is a missing module called **ldap_sso**, and effectively when I review the contents of the ldap module there is no internal module called **ldap_sso**, but in the ldap version `7.x-1.0-beta12` if it is.

How can I update the module in this case?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,
In the mentioned version of ldap, ldap_sso was removed to a separate project, I proceeded to compare the code in case there was any important difference and the result is that they are the same.

So I proceeded to download:

**ldap_sso** from https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap_sso/releases/7.x-1.0-beta15 and

**ldap** from: https://www.drupal.org/project/ldap/releases/7.x-1.0-beta15 (by suggestion of drupal)

Now these modules go separately and I ran the update and it did not give any problem.

regards